# Jquery plugin: pulling data from the invoker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a Jquery plugin and need to access information that resides at the invoker level (i.e. outside the plugin). The following works, however it doesn't seem to be a good practice. What is the best way to access information outside the plugin?

PS: I can't include the function inside the plugin.

The plugin:

```
(function ( $ ) {


    $.fn.test = function() {

        invokerLevelFunction();

        return this;

    };


}( jQuery ));
```

and the javascripts that invokes it, including the global function:

```
function invokerLevelFunction () {
    alert ("Hello");
}

$(document).ready(function () {

     $( "div" ).test();

});  // end document ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as an argument to make sure there are no scope issues

```
function invokerLevelFunction () {
    alert ("Hello");
}

$(document).ready(function () {

     $( "div" ).test(invokerLevelFunction);

});
```

plugin

```
(function ($) {


    $.fn.test = function(callback) {

        // do stuff

        if ( typeof callback == 'function' ) callback();

        return this;

    };


}(jQuery));
```